# How to calculate the total difference in merged cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As you can see on the image, I have lots of different categories (laptops, mobile phones, etc.). I want to calculate the total revenue from the lot I have. Since each lot has its own quantity, I cannot apply the unique formula of the difference here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use sumproduct() like this:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D3:D8-C3:C8)
```

Not typing in more data but you can expand it as needed.

Comment: OP is asking how to get the dynamic range

Comment: @idfurw thanks for the downvote. BTW where did your answer go?

Comment: You got my hoogte, since the OP shows it wants that result.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("D"&ROW(E11)&":D"&ROW(E11)+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(D11:D),0),0)-2))-SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW(E11)&":C"&ROW(E11)+MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(C11:C),0),0)-2))
```